# Does Geolocation Understand Global Variables?

Tags: leaflet, geolocation

I am using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error); to get the user's location in an https web page. I have also defined
var map;
...as a global var.

The success function gets called, but inside that function it doesn't seem to recognize "map" as a global variable. I can initialize the map and set the location of the map inside the success function, but after the success function ends, "map" is undefined again. That causes any other events with map to fail.

How can I get the map variable to be recognized inside of the success function, or return 
position.coords.latitude 
...and
position.coords.longitude

...from the success function so I can initialize the map?

Comment: Which GIS software?

Comment: The map is Leaflet, but no global variables are recognized within the success function().

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, the best solution is to pass the lat/lng in the success function to a second function. The second function sees the global scope and you can initialize the map there. Something like this:

```
if (!navigator.geolocation)
{
    initMapWithoutLocation();
}
function success(position)
{
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    initMapWithGeolocation(lat,lng);      
}// end success  
function failure()
{
  initMapWithoutGeolocation();
}// end failure

// Call the function with the function names for success or failure
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,failure);
```

Your second function, initMapWithGeolocation() in this case cannot be in an instance of a class, because the success() function cannot see the instance. Just send it to a function outside of the success() function.